# Listview items not apearing on the screen

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I'm looking for a simple solution. I want to make different types of exercises appear on a listview. I saw this pattern in a few resources but it's not working for me - nothing showed on the screen in Android Studio or on the emulator. Any suggestions?

listOfExercises is my listview's id

I go from MainActivity to ExerciseTypes via a button, if that's of any use

```
class ExerciseTypes : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise_types)

       this.setTitle("Choose an exercise")
        var exerciseTypes : Array<String> = arrayOf("Match pairs", "Translate")
        
        var exercisesAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, exerciseTypes)
        var listView = listOfExercises
        listView.adapter = exercisesAdapter
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you assigned a `LayoutManager` to your `RecyclerView` anywhere? That's needed before anything will show up.

Comment: No. I have used only ListView. I haven't learned RecyclerView yet. Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

If `listOfExercises` is id of the ListView, you should use `findViewById` or [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) to initialize var/val by the view from XML.

`val listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listOfExercises)`

Result should be like:

```
class ExerciseTypes : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise_types)
        val exerciseTypes: Array<String> = arrayOf("Match pairs", "Translate")
        val exercisesAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, exerciseTypes)
        val listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listOfExercises)
        listView.adapter = exercisesAdapter
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I added Log.d("tag", listView.count.toString()) and the result is 2 , but still nothing on the screen

Comment: @Simona updated my answer - data had successfully been shown